# Amazon Linux Init.d Script Not Daemonizing Properly

Tags: init.d, amazon-linux

I'm working on Amazon Linux and am running into an issue with my init.d script.  I'm trying to run Kibana 4, which is just a script that calls nodejs to run as a service, but it's not working.

Typing `service kibana status` works fine, but whenever I type `service kibana start` the command just hangs (i.e. doesn't run in the background).  When I `Ctrl-C` it, I get a `[FAILED]` response, but the process has been created and is running.

When I look in my `/var/run/` directory for `kibana.pid` I don't see anything, even though the process is actually running.  Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

I have a feeling I'm not using `daemon` correctly...

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#       /etc/init.d/kibana

# Set defaults.
exec="/kibana/kibana-{{ kibana.version }}-linux-x64/bin/kibana > /var/log/kibana/kibana.log"
prog="kibana"
pid_file="/var/run/${prog}.pid"
lock_file="/var/lock/subsys/$prog"
kibana_user="kibana"

# Execute init.d functions
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

case "$1" in
    start)
        echo -n "Start Kibana: "
        daemon --user $kibana_user --pidfile $pid_file $exec
        retval=$?
        echo
        [ $retval -eq 0 ] && touch $lock_file
        ;;
    stop)
        echo -n "Stopping Kibana: "
        su $kibana_user -c "kill `cat $pid_file`"
        retval=$?
        [ $retval -eq 0 ] && rm -f $lock_file
        echo "OK"
        ;;
    status)
        status -p $pid_file kibana
        exit $?
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: `basename $0` start|stop|status"
        exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: By the way, here's the kibana file I'm trying to execute: https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/blob/master/src/server/bin/kibana.sh

Comment: Amazon Linux is generally not compatible with CentOS, and so I've removed all the CentOS references to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Unfortunately, doesn't look like theres much interest in answering a CentOS init.d question.

Comment: I would just advise you to not use Amazon Linux for anything important...or anything at all. It's too unstable.

Comment: I hear you, but this is for a project where that decision can't be reversed.  Any thoughts in general on how I would debug this?

Comment: Well, I can't help you with office politics, which is the only thing that could cause "that decision can't be reversed"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the issue was that `daemon` was not playing nicely with `exec`.  I updated my code to call `kibana` directly and added `&` at the end to get it to daemonize.

**Update:**

Unfortunately, I can't copy the full code I used, but I can tell you that I based it on  https://github.com/chovy/node-startup.  I basically forked this code and made the customizations that made sense for my setup.

Here's the key function in my init.d script:

```
KIBANA_EXEC="/path/to/my/kibana/bin"
LOG_FILE="/path/to/kibana/log/file"
PID_FILE="/path/to/kibana/pid/file"

...

start_it() {
    mkdir -p "$PID_DIR"
    mkdir -p "$LOG_DIR"

    # This is an artifact of the way I set things up and is a hacky solution to
    # fix a race condition, so copy with caution
    sleep 10

    echo "Starting Kibana..."
    $KIBANA_EXEC 1>"$LOG_FILE" 2>&1 &
    echo $! > "$PID_FILE"
    echo "Kibana started with pid $!"
}
```

Comment: Yes, doesn't look like there's a command-line option to make kibana fork and return, ie run as a daemon so it has to be backgrounded in bash with '&'.  Possibly `nohup` or `disown` would help as well.  Could you maybe show your code changes for the benefit of anyone with a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've just been going through this issue and created a solution based on Josh's above. It get's around the 'sleep 10' issue by using a chkconfig header that ensures that the script waits for suitable services to be available before attempting to start. Heres my init.d script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Kibana    Init script for Kibana
#
# chkconfig: 345 99 76
# processname: kibana
#
KIBANA_EXEC="/opt/kibana/bin/kibana"
now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%S")
LOG_FILE="/opt/kibana/bin/log/kibana.$now.log"
PID_FILE="/opt/kibana/bin/log/kibana.$now.pid"
RETVAL=0

start() {
    echo "Starting Kibana..."
    $KIBANA_EXEC 1>"$LOG_FILE" 2>&1 &
    echo $! > "$PID_FILE"
    echo "Kibana started with pid $!"
}

case "$1" in
    start)
    start
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start}"
        exit 0
    ;;
esac
exit $RETVAL
```

You'll then need to update the script permissions and register the service (don't forget to create a suitable logging directory and set the correct paths for kibana, log and pid location etc:

```
sudo chmod 0755 /etc/init.d/kibana
sudo chkconfig kibana on
```